# How to get control to other item in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal `recyclerView`,when I clicked on each of the element,a `LinearLayout` inside it `setVisibility(VISIBLE)` ,this work fine.

So what I want now is,when I clicked in current item,`LinearLayout` `setVisibilty(VISIBLE)`(as usual) at the same time,if I clicked another item before,the `LinearLayout` inside it `setVisibility(GONE)`.

**What I tried so far**

```
 viewHolder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   if(viewHolder.linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        //hide
        viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        int nowClickedId = 0;
        //hide LinearLayout of other position that clicked before
        if(nowClickedId !=  position){
            viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

         //show for current clicked item
          viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         //get current item position store at the array
          nowClickedId = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        }
    }
});
```

So far I just have control at the item in current position,how can get the control of the item of clicked previously?

Comment: Why do you write `int nowClickedId = 0;` in the else block ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a variable to store the position of the item clicked and declare it globally.

```
private int nowclicked=-1;
```

Now inside your viewholder whenever position is clicked store it to the global variable and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` which notifies the adapter that data is changed.

```
private class Sample extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public Sample(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        viewHolder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nowclicked = getAdapterPosition();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the `onBindViewHolder` if the posistion is equal show `linearLayout` else hide it.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

  if(nowclicked==position){
      viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }else {
      viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```

Comment: the second block of code is writing inside the `ViewHolder` class??

Comment: Sample code should be in your viewholder class.Follow this code your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write this code inside the onBindViewHolder() method and ensure to write

```
holder.viewHolder.container.setOnClickListener();
```

And according the position you can do whatever you want.